# How assign names for each list[[i]] in a huge list file

Tags: r, list, names

I have a very big list `file.dput()` function for two of them is as below :

```
> dput(mydata).....  
      `NA` = c("SHC2", "GRB2", "HRAS", "KRAS", "NRAS", "SHC3", 
            "MAPK1", "MAPK3", "MAP2K1", "MAP2K2", "RAF1", "SHC1", "SOS1", 
            "YWHAB", "CDK1"), `NA` = c("NUP50", "NUPL2", "PSIP1", "NUP35", 
            "NUP205", "NUP210", "NUP188", "NUP62", "SLC25A4", "SLC25A5", 
            "SLC25A6", "HMGA1", "NUP43", "KPNA1", "NUP88", "NUP54", "NUP133", 
            "NUP107", "RANBP2", "LOC645870", "TPR", "NUP37", "NUP85", 
            "NUP214", "AAAS", "SEH1L", "RAE1", "BANF1", "NUP155", "NUP93", 
            "NUPL1", "POM121", "NUP153"), ....
```

I'm also have a file including names, but I can't assign it, 
names(mydata)<-list("a", "b")# clears former data and replaces with "a" and "b"
names(mydata)<-c("a", "b")

I have tried using names(mydata) but it dosen't do what I need. I think "N" should be the name which I dont know how to access it. right?
If yes what should I do? Regards**

Comment: please show your full attempt at assigning names and the error message you are getting, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you want to name the elements of a list with the names from another file, here's how to do it:

```
x <- list (1,2,3,4,5)
y <- LETTERS [1:5]
names (x) <- y
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
The problem was: I was using [[ ]] to recruit names but [] should be used for names:

```
x <- list (1,2,3,4,5)
y <- LETTERS [1:5]
names (x) <- y

> x[[1]]
[1] 1

> x[1]
$A
[1] 1

> x[2]
$B
[1] 2
```

Comment: This is why you need to make your question as clear as possible. We can't guess what is wrong until you show us what you did and why you think it is wrong... Having very big objects should not be a problem, learn to make a small reproducible example like @user3569035 just did.